# Problemas con .write...la salida no es lo esperado

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un programa en el que tomo el mismo valor de un punto en 8 txt diferentes y quiero que la salida sea un txt en el que aparezcan 1.048.576 filas x 8 columnas, pero a la hora de obtener la salida me salen los numeros juntos con más de 8 columnas..

He probado de todo poniendo \n dentro del bucle for(j....) como fuera...¿alguien sabría decirme en qué fallo?

¿Sale así por la gran cantidad de datos?

Muchísimas gracias

```
package ber.unico.com;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FiltroUnico {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    int n=1048576;       
    float datos[][] = new float[n][8];

    Scanner sc1,sc2,sc3,sc4,sc5,sc6,sc7,sc8;

    try {
        sc1 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\jose\\Desktop\\f1.txt"));
        sc2 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\jose\\Desktop\\f2.txt"));
        sc3 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\jose\\Desktop\\f3.txt"));
        sc4 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\jose\\Desktop\\f4.txt"));
        sc5 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\jose\\Desktop\\f5.txt"));
        sc6 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\jose\\Desktop\\f6.txt"));
        sc7 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\jose\\Desktop\\f7.txt"));
        sc8 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\jose\\Desktop\\f8.txt"));

        FileWriter fw;
        fw = new FileWriter(newFile("C:\\Users\\jose\\Desktop\\Salid.txt"));

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){

            if (sc1.hasNextFloat()) {
                datos[i][0] = sc1.nextFloat();
            }


            if (sc2.hasNextFloat()) {
                datos[i][1] = sc2.nextFloat();
            }


            if (sc3.hasNextFloat()) {
                datos[i][2] = sc3.nextFloat();
            }


            if (sc4.hasNextFloat()) {
                datos[i][3] = sc4.nextFloat();                 
            }


            if (sc5.hasNextFloat()) {
                datos[i][4] = sc5.nextFloat();                 
            }


            if (sc6.hasNextFloat()) {
                datos[i][5] = sc6.nextFloat();                 
            }


            if (sc7.hasNextFloat()) {
                datos[i][6] = sc7.nextFloat();                 
            }


            if (sc8.hasNextFloat()) {
                datos[i][7] = sc8.nextFloat();                  
            }


            for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
                System.out.print(datos[i][j] + " ");
                fw.write(datos[i][j] + " ");

            }

            System.out.println();
        }

        fw.flush();
        fw.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En el ejemplo que has puesto no estas escribiendo un salto de linea en el fichero,`System.out.println()` solo está pasando a la siguiente línea en la salida estándar.

Tienes que poner `fw.write(System.lineSeparator())` a la misma altura que tienes el  `System.out.println()`.

Comment: respuesta simple, clara y exacta :). +1

Comment: Genial hermano...Mil gracias :D <3